# DateTime formats used in InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, datetime-format, invariantculture

I have to pre-validate in Javascript a string that will be a DateTime in c#. 
The DateTime parse uses InvariantCulture.

Does anyone know the DateTime formats defined for InvariantCulture?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Compiling information from [standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings):

| Pattern | Example |
| --- | --- |
| Short Date Pattern ("d") | `MM/dd/yyyy` |
| Long Date Pattern ("D") | `dddd, dd MMMM yyyy` |
| Full Date Short Time ("f") | `dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm` |
| Full Date Long Time ("F") | `dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss` |
| General Date Short Time ("g") | `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm` |
| General Date Long Time ("G") | `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` |
| Month ("M", "m") | `MMMM dd` |
| Round-Trip ("O", "o") | `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK` |
| RFC1123 ("R", "r") | `ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT` |
| Sortable ("s") | `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` |
| Short Time ("t") | `HH:mm` |
| Long Time ("T") | `HH:mm:ss` |
| Universal Sortable ("u") | `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ` |
| Universal Full ("U") | `dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss` |
| Year Month ("Y", "y") | `yyyy MMMM` |

Comment: Seeming as `MM/dd/yyyy` is used almost exclusively by Americans (`en-US`) but `InvariantCulture` is ostensibly meant to be universal, it would have been better if `InvariantCulture` used ISO 8601 (`yyyy-MM-dd` and `HH:mm:ss`)  date and time formats instead of its current format. It means I can't use `InvariantCulture` for appropriate culture-neutral logging, for example.

Comment: To expand on my comment above (from 3 years ago) [I have posted copy-and-pastable code that gives you `InvariantCultureWithIso8601` which is an immutable ISO 8601 `CultureInfo` instance, with some handy `DateTime` extension methods too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12447289/159145). HTH.

Comment: @Dai if you know what you want (yyyy-MM-dd and HH:mm:ss), then you can specify that. InvariantCulture just make some guarantees, but it doesn't matter that much which ones are picked, as long as they never change.

Answer (score 15):

It's very easy to test.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var d = DateTime.Now;

    Console.WriteLine("Date format (long):  {0}", d.ToString("D", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Console.WriteLine("Date format (short): {0}", d.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Console.WriteLine("Full format (long):  {0}", d.ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Console.WriteLine("Full format (short): {0}", d.ToString("f", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Console.WriteLine("Time format (long):  {0}", d.ToString("T", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Console.WriteLine("Time format (short): {0}", d.ToString("t", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Console.WriteLine("General format (long):  {0}", d.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Console.WriteLine("General format (short): {0}", d.ToString("g", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

}

Output:

```
Date format (long):  Monday, 16 October 2017
Date format (short): 10/16/2017
Full format (long):  Monday, 16 October 2017 20:12:45
Full format (short): Monday, 16 October 2017 20:12
Time format (long):  20:12:45
Time format (short): 20:12
General format (long):  10/16/2017 20:12:45
General format (short): 10/16/2017 20:12
```

Code on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2VMQl6).

Answer (score 7):

Its more or less the same as en-us but uses as 24 hour time instead of 12 hour am/pm and fills in full MM/DD/YYYY.

```
var date1 = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);   // "05/21/2014 22:09:28"
var date2 = d.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));       // "5/21/2014 10:09:28 PM"
```

Answer (score 2):

- "O" or "o":  `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzz`
- "R" or "r":  `ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss`
- "s":         `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`
- "u":         `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ`

Sources [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings