# C# regular expression to parse a string sometimes containing extra space next to the digit

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

I am trying to alter the reg. expression below to take into account an extra space between the month and the day as follows:

```
(?:(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\s\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}

rats 1.4K Sep  9 08:10 /opt/rats/prod ===> it returns blank
rats 1.4K Sep 12 08:10 /opt/rats/prod ===> returns "Sep 12 08:10"

If I add \s it works in the first string but it breaks on the second string:

(?:(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\s\s\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}
```

Thank you

Comment: Match for 1 or 2 spaces the same way you're matching for 1 or 2 digits, with `\s{1,2}`.

Comment: Why arent you just parsing using `DateTime.TryParse()`?  You obviously have some text before the date, but it looks like it is a constant, so just remove it before parsing

Comment: @maccettura: parsing depends on the culture of the user so TryParse cannot provide me that plus if it fails I dont get an exception, it will return me a 1/1 bogus date.

Comment: @Max `TryParse()` returns a bool, so you know if it fails.  Also, wouldnt your regex be culture dependent since its in English?  You can always [use `InvarianatCulture`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778141/datetime-formats-used-in-invariantculture) too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match exactly extra space

```
(?:(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\s{1,2}\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}
```

To match any count of extra spaces

```
(?:(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\s+\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}
```

Comment: @Max Is the text before and after the date always the same?  If it is not the same text, is the order still the same (e.g The date is always the 2nd, 3rd and 4th index)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `\s{1}\d{2}` or `\s{2}\d{1}`

```
(?:(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))(\s{1}\d{2}|\s{2}\d{1})\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}
```